# Sin appearing in u-substitution and I can't figure out why

Tags: calculus, substitution

I came across this in Khan Academy Integral Calculus.  I am asked to find this integral...
[image]

I did the substitution, and it made sense so far...
[image]

Then, I was unable to figure how to solve the definite integral. This was their solution...

[image]

Where did that sin expression come from?  I am so confused!

Comment: The substitution $u = \sin x$ was made, although that should have been specified.

Comment: Do you know the derivative of your inverse trig functions?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Given the way that most intro calculus texts are written, I would imagine that the student is expected to read the integral off of a table, *maybe* after having seen the derivation once, with no real context. I am particularly certain that this is how Khan approaches things, as that site seems to be more focused on rote memorization than understanding. :(

Comment: @nuggethead Please do not use images to convey information which can be conveyed as text.  For details about *why* you shouldn't use images as you have done, please read https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/ .  That post also provides links to the MathJax tutorial, which should help you figure out how to correctly typeset your mathematics.

Comment: Finally, just for the record, this question has been asked-and-answered on this site in the past.  For example, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1409813/ .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The derivative of $\sin^{-1}(u)$ is $1 / \sqrt{1 - u^2}$, so the indefinite integral of $1/\sqrt{1 - u^2}$ is $\sin^{-1}(u) + C$. One way to understand where this comes from is to use implicit differentiation. Suppose $$y = \sin^{-1}(u)$$ (and note for later that we're implicitly restricting the values of $u$ and $y$, with $-1 \leq u \leq 1$ and $-\pi/2 \leq y \leq \pi/2$). Then $$\sin(y) = u.$$ Now differentiate on both sides with respect to $u$:
$$
\frac{d}{du}\left[\sin(y)\right] = \frac{d}{du}[u] \\
\cos(y) \frac{dy}{du} = 1 \\
\frac{dy}{du} = \frac{1}{\cos(y)}.
$$
So now we just need to understand why $\cos(y) = \cos(\sin^{-1}(u)) = \sqrt{1 - u^2}$. If $0 \leq y \leq \pi/2$, then we can imagine that $y$ is one angle of a right triangle with opposite side $u$ and hypotenuse 1:

[image: right triangle with angle y, opposite side u, and hypotenuse 1]

By the Pythagorean Theorem, the base is $\sqrt{1 - u^2}$, so $$\frac{dy}{du} = \frac{1}{\cos(y)} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - u^2}}.$$ And if instead $-\pi/2 \leq y \leq 0$, then using the fact that sine is odd and cosine is even, we have $\cos(y) = \cos(-y) = \sqrt{1 - (-u)^2} = \sqrt{1 - u^2}$, and we get the same answer.